# Installing Components in C++Builder says can't find .h file when files are .hpp?

Tags: c++builder

I've installed a couple of different 3rd party components, one of which is Fast Reports Pro.

They give weird issues. They typically install, then I can add the components to my form. But when I try to go to the `.cpp` file/tab, it says it can't find the `xxx.h` file. There is none, but I can search and find the `.hpp` file, which may be `xxx.hpp` or could be `Xxxx.hpp` (that is, it's a slightly different name).

I choose to add the path when selecting it, too. Then after I do that, when I try to build, it says it can't find that file.  So, I remove it from the `.cpp` file and it builds, it adds it back and compiles, but many times it can't link because it's missing some file (either `.lib` or `.obj`), but maybe I do a new build and it links fine.

What the heck could be happening? Is there something I need to check / reinstall with C++Builder 11.3?

Answer (score 0):

I found what is causing these issues. Apparently many of the makers of the components aren't aware of C++Builder having two compilers that maintain totally separate include/library paths.  I found the installers were updating the global classic paths but not the modern compiler paths.  I copied over the entries from the classic paths to the modern paths to fix it up.